# How use two different loops under a for loop in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

We have to compute how many times a number greater than 130 and a number less than -70 occurred in the 2nd column of each row in an excel sheet, saved as a csv file. I need a loop but i already had a loop above it for computing a different column in the rows. I can't seem to get a code that loops around all the row[4] and compute it into one variable. Here is my code.

```
import csv
import os
total = 0
count = 0
ring = 0
column = []
with open("2.5_week.csv") as source:
    rdr = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
    next(rdr, None) # to skip the header

    for row in rdr:
        if float(row[4]):
            total = total + float(row[4])
            count = count + 1  
        while (float(row[2]) >= 130 and float(row[2]) <= -70):
            ring = ring + 1
            print(ring)
        percent = (ring/count) * 100
        ave = total / count
    print (ave, percent)
```

It works for the if loop and prints the 'ave' but seems to skip the while loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: your while loop is probably not evaluating to true.

Comment: There are no numbers that are greater than 130 and also less than -70. Your condition can never be true.  (If the condition ever were true, your while loop would also run forever because you never change the value of row[2] inside it...)

Comment: yeah, that would do it.

Comment: Good thing that while loop is never true, because if it was, it would run forever because the value of `row` never changes in the loop. Sure you don't just want an `if` there?

Comment: loops never get skipped.  There is always an evaluation that happens.  It may skip the loop statements, but the condition is always check each iteration of the "for"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `float(row[2]) >= 130 and float(row[2]) <= -70` is logically incorrect. Lets say the number is 230, so `230>=130` is true but `230<=-70` is false and hence the condition evaluates to false.

So use this:

```
while (float(row[2]) >= 130 or float(row[2]) <= -70) #or instead of and
```

Comment: Why do you think that there is no number greater than 130?

Comment: So what happens if the number is 150? The `while` loop isn't entered because the condition `150 >= 130` matches, but `150 <= -70` does not. The values are **not** the problem, the comparison is the problem.

Comment: @JessyWhite glad I coud help :)